# How to get frames (size and coordinates) for different views in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I need to get frames for multiple views inside a VStack. I think using the `GeometryReader` but it returns the necessary parameters only for the parent. How can I get these parameters for each view on the screenshot below?

[image: Layout I need to get frames for]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60495440/12233264 this might help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the GeometryReader inside the overlay on needed views and store necessary frames in an array or as separate variables.

```swift
ForEach(0..<n) { number in
  YourView()
    .overlay(
      GeometryReader { geometry in
        Color.clear
          .onAppear {
            self.buttonFrames[number] = geometry.frame(in: .global)
          }
        }
    )
}
```

For more details, you can check this source: https://github.com/twostraws/SwiftOnSundays/blob/master/020%20Switcharoo/Project/Switcharoo/ContentView.swift
and the full tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ffV_fYcFoX0